# Unity: Instantiating prefab on GameObject - Error Object is null

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

In my Unity game I have a vehicle prefab working with Edy's Vehicle Physics asset. I'm trying to instantiate a chosen vehicle prefab on the position and rotation of a GameObject.

When running my code in my scene to spawn a vehicle I get this error

> ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null
>
> ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.
>   UnityEngine.Object.CheckNullArgument (System.Object arg, System.String message) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.cs:239)
>   UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.cs:151)
>   UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[VehicleController] (EVP.VehicleController original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.cs:206)
>   VehicleSpawner.spawnVehiclesInFirstGarage () (at Assets/Scripts/VehicleSpawner.cs:44)
>   HandleGarage.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/HandleGarage.cs:59)

[image: script]

Vehicle Prefab is empty because the vehicle will be chosen by the user in game. (Even if I select a vehicle prefab I still get same error)

My code for instantiating the vehicle prefab on the game object

```
public EVP.VehicleTelemetry telemetryComponent;
public EVP.VehicleController vehiclePrefab;
public GameObject spawnObject;

public void spawnVehiclesInFirstGarage ()
{
    // Load saved JSON
    string jsonData = SecurePlayerPrefs.GetString ("vehicleNames");

    // Convert to Class
    Database loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<Database> (jsonData);

    // Loop through Owned Vehicles Garage
    for (int i = 0; i < loadedData.vehicleNames.Count; i++) {

        // Set up instantiate
        var vehicle = Resources.Load("Prefabs/" + (loadedData.vehicleNames [i]));
        vehiclePrefab = vehicle as EVP.VehicleController;

        // Spawn vehicle on game object
        EVP.VehicleController newVehicle = Instantiate(vehiclePrefab, spawnObject.transform.position, spawnObject.transform.rotation) as EVP.VehicleController;
        telemetryComponent.target = newVehicle;
    }
}
```

Comment: After `var vehicle = Resources.Load("Prefabs/" + (loadedData.vehicleNames [i]));`, what does `Debug.Log(vehicle);` yield?

Comment: I get the name of the selected prefab "Sport Coupe (UnityEngine.GameObject)"

Comment: Could you show the full class?

Comment: that's the only code being used to instantiate. I call the function when the scene is started

Comment: I added the full error message in the question. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: I have some suspicions, and some possible solutions. Added them as an answer as it would be too long for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible Solutions

1. The `vehiclePrefab = vehicle as EVP.VehicleController;` could be causing problems, as logging `var vehicle = Resources.Load("Prefabs/" + (loadedData.vehicleNames [i]));`, already gives `Sport Coupe (UnityEngine.GameObject)`, which is the correct type.

   Instead of using `as EVP.VehicleController`, try:

   ```
   // Set up instantiate
   var vehiclePrefab = Resources.Load("Prefabs/" + (loadedData.vehicleNames [i])) as GameObject;

   // Spawn vehicle on game object
   GameObject newVehicle = Instantiate(vehiclePrefab, spawnObject.transform.position, spawnObject.transform.rotation);
   EVP.VehicleController controller = newVehicle.GetComponent<EVP.VehicleController>();
   telemetryComponent.target = newVehicle;
   ```

   This is from [Unity's documentation for loading prefabs via scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).
2. From the error message, it seems that `spawnVehiclesInFirstGarage()` is being called in `void Start()`. If so, try putting it in the `void Update()`, adding a `if( prefab != null && !isInstantiated)` check.

### Additional Troubleshooting (if the solutions don't work)

- Try assigning a prefab via the inspector and see if you get the same problem.
- On your existing code, try `Debug.Log(vehiclePrefab)`.

Comment: thanks for the help! In the instantiate line. I got an error saying `Cannot convert type GameObject to VehicleController`

Comment: The vehicle prefab would need to be a VehicleController component.

Comment: @BroSimple I assume VehicleController is a MonoBehaviour. In which case, simply use `GetComponent<VehicleController>()`. I've updated the answer to show how to do this

Comment: It instantiated! Thank you! but I've been trying to mess with the code but I still can't seem to go around the same error `cannot convert GameObject to VehicleController` in `telemetryComponent.target = newVehicle`

Comment: can I do the same as I did with `VehicleController` on `GetComponent` to `VehicleTelemetry`? or would it replace `VehicleController`?

Comment: You can do `VehicleTelemetry vTel = newVehicle.GetComponent<VehicleTelemetry>()`. This assumes you have the `VehicleTelemetry` monobehaviour attached to your prefab as well

Comment: For a quick dirty guide to unity, you may want to refer to [my article here](https://blog.crazy.technology/post/Introduction-to-Unity3D-21c7f860). In the meantime, do mark this as answered :) thank u

Comment: I'm just going to open a new post for this error but thank you!

Comment: The thing is `VehicleTelemetry` only accepts a `VehicleController` object not just `GameObject` but I can't convert it

Comment: Are you referring to `telemetryComponent.target = newVehicle;`? If you are, maybe change it to `telemetryComponent.target = newVehicle.GetComponent<EVP.VehicleController>();` ?

Comment: Or simply, from existing answer, `telemetryComponent.target = controller;`

Comment: Thank you so much, everything works! I will be reading your blog tutorials!